# UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled returns wrong value

Tags: ios

I am using UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession function to lock ipad in single app mode.
 When device restarts I am checking whether iPad is in single app mode or not using function UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled() it is alway returning NO , even if device is actually in single app mode

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm actually having the same problem, UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled always returns false no matter if I started guided access or not.

Comment: what version of ios are you guys using? 11.4.1 I have the same issue